# List admin services used by WSO2 carbon based servers?

Tags: wso2

You can list down all the Admin Services used by WSO2 carbon based products using following steps.

1. Start the server with OSGI console. Go to the `<SERVER_HOME>/bin`
    using command shell.

   i) Eg : Linux

   ```
      sh wso2server.sh -DosgiConsole
   ```

   ii) Windows

   ```
       wso2server.bat -DosgiConsole
   ```
2. After successfully started the server, press enter.
3. Type listAdminServices and press enter.
4. Now you should be able to see the list of Admin Service names with endpoint URLS.

Thanks & Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 2):

You have provided the question and answer both :) However I just like to add more in to this;

If you want to retrieve the WSDLs of admin services of WSO2 Identity Server; Go to `CARBON_HOME/repository/conf` directory and change the value of the `HideAdminServiceWSDLs` in `carbon.xml` file like below and restart the server.

```
<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>true</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>
```

to

```
<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>
```

Then you can retrieve the WSDLs by browsing the service by adding "?wsdl" option.

For example, if you can find entitlement service

```
https://{Hostname}:{port}/services/EntitlementService?wsdl
```