# saml renew with wso2 Identiy server SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, wso2-identity-server

In wso2 is 4.0.3 I use the method *org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.ui.client.SAMLSSOServiceClient.validate()* to renew a session via SSO web services.

I've switched to is 4.2.0 but cannot find that method.

Is there a ws client to call the SSO web services?

Answer (score 0):

Yes..  Web service is still there which is "SAMLSSOService". You can find the WSDL of this service. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219907/list-admin-services-used-by-wso2-carbon-based-servers) SO question for it. With 450, there is no "SAMLSSOServiceClient" implementation.  Because "samlsso" servlet has been brought in to the Backend (earlier it was in front end). Therefore web service call is not needed to be done for BE service.

Comment: So how can the saml token be renewd? In the past version I used the session index attribute, but now it doesn't work, because the session is saved with the ssotokenid cookie.

Comment: What is use case for renewing token? Because, you can retrieve new token. With SAML2 SSO it is rare to provide a renew API.  AFAIK,  still SSO session is stored with respect to the seesionIndex attribute

Comment: The use case is: a Service provider use the SSO to build the application principal, then use the saml token to call web services protected with ws security. so the renew is needed when the saml token expires. How can I retrieve new token without username and password?

Comment: Yes..Got your point.. It means that you have called WSO2IS API for returning another token. Actually, once token is expired, you can initialize the SAML2 SSO flow, As you have already authenticated with IDP, you do not want to enter user/pass, and you would be directed back with SAML token.  You can configure SAML token expire time and IDP session time using identity.xml file