# can wso2 identification provide authorization service for third party application

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have one application which is Client/server based using C#, and I know I can use wso2 identification server to perform authentication by soap.

Now I want to know is it possible to let identification server store my application permissions, store relationship between group/role and permissions, so that I can check whether a user has a corresponding permission.

If I can do this, what if I have several applications (yes, I do have at least 4 applications that's why I want to utilize identification server to perform unified authorization service)?  How do I store permissions for different applications? Is there anybody practice this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.. there are two approaches

1. Use XACML capabilities of the WSO2IS. This is the standard way. WSO2IS can act as XACML PDP. You can create policies for different applications and use them to evaluate the results. You can find more details omn XACML and WSO2IS from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/). This is the
2. Use "AuthorizationAdminService" services. This is a custom way. WSO2IS stores permission data in the its database and you can use above web service API manage it. `https://localhost/services/AuthorizationAdminService?wsdl`  You can see the WSDL of this service. for that, please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219907/list-admin-services-used-by-wso2-carbon-based-servers) OS question