# wso2 identification server authorization api

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am trying to use wso2 identification server as authorization center:
there are several system, they share same user information
I want them to utilize identification server to perform authentication and authorization

In current research, I have found the API which I can use to perform authentication, and also soap api to perform user/group/permission management soap api
But I could not find the api which I can use to perform authorization request? So far those code are written in AuthrozationMgrJDBCImpl, there is no soap API expose those API.

Is there anybody know such API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. WSO2 Identity Server can be used as centralized authorization management. There are two approaches

1. Use XACML capabilities of the WSO2IS. This is the standard way. WSO2IS can act as XACML PDP. You can create policies for different appolications. PDP is exposed as web service API, Application can call this web service API to receive authorization decision based on the policies. You can see the WSDL by pointing to `https://localhost:9443/services/EntitlementService?wsdl`. You can find more details on XACML and WSO2IS from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/).
2. Use "AuthorizationAdminService" services. This is a custom way that you have referred. WSO2IS stores permission data in its own database and manage it through JDBCAuthorizationManager. However it only supports for RBAC. (in XACML you can use ABAC). you can see the WSDL by pointing to `https://localhost:9443/services/AuthorizationAdminService?wsdl`.

Note : You can see the WSDL of this service. But it is not exposed by default. Please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219907/list-admin-services-used-by-wso2-carbon-based-servers) OS question.  Also "AuthorizationAdminService" service available only after WSO2IS 450 version.