# WSO2 Identity Server Web Services Documentation

Tags: web-services, wsdl, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am doing a comparison between some Identity Management tools, one of which is the WSO2 Identity Server. I have found a number of wsdl files regarding WSO2 IS web services.
Is there any kind of documentation regarding operations in the wsdl files? Because i can't seam to find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Identity Server contains many web service APIs.. These APIs mainly support for identity and entitlement management functions.  You can find web service API such as `UserAdmin`, `RemoteUserStoreManagerService` , `EntitlementService` and so on.  But there are some web service APIs for server management functions..  All the UI that you see in WSO2IS server,  calls backend web service APIs to get the operation done.. Unfortunately there is no any good document on explaining all these web service APIs. But if you are looking some specific function, You can find them.. As an example, if you want to use WSO2IS as authorization server, You must look about  `EntitlementService` API. More detail on it can be found [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/06/13/pdp-pep-communication-wso2is/). Like that, You can search for some specific topic about WSO2IS in the internet..and get some details about these service.

But, If you like to list and see all WSDL of WSO2IS, You go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219907/list-admin-services-used-by-wso2-carbon-based-servers) question that is asked in SO. Actually by looking at the WSDL,  You can even get some idea about the functions.

Comment: I am looking for basic admin user management operation(e.g add/remove/list/update users) and role management operations. Are there any javadocs available to help me understand operations defined in wsdl files. (Many operations can be found multiple times throughout different wdsl files)

Comment: Then please use https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl  WSDL is simple,  you can understand easily.. use SOAP UI to try this out.... You can find Java client to invoke this server from here https://github.com/soasecurity/soasecurity/tree/master/user-mgt/client/remote-user-400